# MobileConnect queueMO API not re-opting in a "Not Opted In" / Opted Out contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect

I'm trying to resubscribe an opted-out contact.

This is the API code I'm executing through PostMan and the response is **result:OK**

```
{   
    "subscribers":[    
     {   
       "mobilenumber": "XXXXXXXXX888",    
       "subscriberkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAAY"   
     }
   ],    
   "shortCode" : "XXXXXXXXX403",    
   "messageText" : "GB_REORDERSUB"    
}
```

However the status of the contacts keyword subscription is still "**Not Opted In**"
[image]

Does someone know why does this behave this way?

Comment: IS the keyword gb_reordersub have an optin messages associated to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1-

Create a opt-in keyword and ask your subscribers to opt-in using that keyword.

Option #2-

For the MobileConnect contacts, there are 2 parts to it - MobileConnect Demographics(under attributes tab) and Mobile Subscription(under the membership tab)

Changing the status from opt-in to opt-out can be done using Import file/API/Import mobile contacts activity. But when you try to re-subscribe using any of the three methods, although you will receive a success message but the status will change to 'Active' only for MobileConnect Demographics and for subscription it will still be 'Not opted in'.

The only way i could update this is by using the SSJS. Since you already have an installed package, replace the values with yours in the code mentioned in the below article -

https://code4.cloud/articles/sfmc-subscribe-mobile-numbers-to-short-code-with-mobileconnect-rest-api/